# Vuetify <v-toolbar-title> and links that do not change formating

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

It looks like you can use the to in  so the router link extends.  I want to make the  link to the the front page.   does not work and wrapping  in  changes the formatting.  How can I make <-v-toolbar-title> link without changing the formatting?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the component code, that would really help to solve your issue..

Comment: @chans in Codepen:

Comment: https://codepen.io/jasonbunnell/pen/GRRmrPE

Comment: thanks for the codepen, just create a sample vuetify project and reproduced the UI with your code, Please check the below answer. Let me know if that resolves your issue

Comment: I put the full project on GitHub here:

Comment: https://github.com/jasonbunnell/bunnell-assoc

Answer (score 6):

*There is a perfect way to handle this situation.*

> Use click event handler to navigate to the front page

**Just replace your v-toolbar-title code with the following code.**

```
<v-toolbar-title @click="$router.push('/')" class="headline text-uppercase" >
  <span class="display-1 text-uppercase font-weight-medium">Company&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="display-1 text-uppercase font-weight-light">Associates</span>
</v-toolbar-title>
```

> This way its very clean without adding any external css or additional
>   button component  just by adding this "$router.push('/')" to @click
>   event handler

Comment: Are you using vue-router in your project ??

Comment: Yes.  router.js not index.js in router directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll be content with any response to this issue because it'll involve at least *some* customization.

If you're not happy with the other solutions here is another one: https://codepen.io/simondepelchin/pen/PooRyBG

What I did is replace the `v-toolbar-title` with a `router-link` and manually added the `v-toolbar__title` class that is added by Vuetify. Also note that in order to keep default styling you have to specify the link's tag which should be `div` in this case.

Here's the code snippet:

```html
<router-link 
    tag="div"
    :to="{ path: '/' }" 
    class="v-toolbar__title headline text-uppercase">
    <span class="display-1 text-uppercase font-weight-medium">Company&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="display-1 text-uppercase font-weight-light">Associates</span>
</router-link>
```

Just be aware that in case Vuetify updates and changes the class used for the `v-toolbar-title` you might have to change it too.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is the below one. There is no out of the box solution as fas as I know.

```html
<v-toolbar-title>
    <v-btn text to="/">home</v-btn>
</v-toolbar-title>
```

```css
.theme--light.v-btn--active:hover::before,
.theme--light.v-btn--active::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.theme--dark.v-btn--active:hover::before,
.theme--dark.v-btn--active::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Then, [@chans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10555785/chans)'s answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simplified version using v-btn and plain. class to center title is optional.

```
   <v-toolbar-title class="flex text-center">
    <v-btn plain to="/">Title</v-btn>
   </v-toolbar-title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is to apply a custom class:

```
<v-toolbar-title class="my-button">
    <v-btn text to="/">home</v-btn>
</v-toolbar-title>
```

and then force the specific button(s) with CSS:

```
<style scoped>
/deep/ .my-button .v-btn--plain .v-btn__content {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
</style>
```

This worked for me and no matter which element I choose from the drawer, the opacity stays as is.